# When do succubi mature?

Tags: lotte-no-omocha

In Lotte no Omocha, Astarotte Ygvar is a 10-year-old succubus. We know that she must create a harem before she matures, she will need to create a harem so that she can have a steady supply of "sáðfryma".

Do succubi mature at the same speed as humans (finishing puberty sometime between the ages of 15 and 17) or does puberty come earlier or later for succubi?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is a panel from chapter 2 of the manga. It states that Astarotte will become an adult in the next 3 years.

[image]

Given that she's 10 at the start of the story, it seems that she'll be matured to the level of needing a harem by the age of 13. That would correspond to roughly the middle of puberty in human girls, so it seems likely that succubi mature at roughly the same rate as humans, though perhaps slightly faster.